# Range of a function (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

The question goes like this (an elementary analysis question):

> Let $g:\Re \to \Re$ defined by $$g(x)=99x^3-999x^2+9999$$ What is the range og $g$?

I believe that the range of $g$ is $\Re$. But is there a theorem saying this? I can only think of Intermediate Value Theorem and Extreme Value Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the conventional notation for the real numbers is $\mathbb R$. The symbol $\Re$ denotes the real part of some complex number.

You are right that the range is $\mathbb R$. One way to prove this is to show that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x)=\infty,$$
and$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} g(x)=-\infty.$$
Then you can use the intermediate value theorem to conclude that $g$ has all of $\mathbb R$ in its image.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
But the IVT requires that $f$ continuous on a closed interval, how can I prove the interval $(-\infty , \infty)$?

Comment: @IDontKnowMath Suppose you want to get the value $x\in \mathbb R$. You know $g$ attains some really big value $a>x$ at some point $p$, and some really negative value $b<x$ at some point $q$. Then use the interval $[q,p]$ and apply the IVT.